# Use an iFrame without session or cookie data (incognito)

Tags: javascript, html, session, iframe, cookies

If you use an `iFrame` element in an HTML document, the child page will load with all of the session and cookie data from the browser.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stack Overflow in an iFrame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Stack Overflow in an iFrame</h1>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" width="640" height="480" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Ignore for a moment that SO doesn't actually allow itself to be loaded in an iFrame. If it did, the SO page loaded by the iFrame would show you as signed in.

**How can I use an iFrame without any cookies or session data?** (like incognito mode in Chrome)

*Why?*

My company sells a product (web-app) for people to build customized websites with. When they are authenticated, and they visit their website, we show them the auth'ed version of the UI so that they can edit the content. Un-auth'ed users only see the static website. Using multiple browsers or clearing cookies is not a reasonable expectation of our users so we want to show a preview of their site to them in an iFrame so they can see what their visitors would see. We also want to show "mobile" previews of the site with smaller resolution iFrames so that they may see what their visitors would see if they came to the website on a phone. These iFrame(s) need to be loaded without access to the browser's cookies or session data so that they load in un-auth'ed mode, just like Chrome does in incognito mode.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start. I did find out that [HTML5 added some `sandbox` attribute values to the `iFrame` element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp), but none of them seem to help with this problem. Maybe something could be done with JavaScript, we do already use jQuery in our project.

Note: We aim to only use valid HTML5

Comment: You can **not** control cookie access from the client. My company also does a ton of stuff within an iFrame, so setting cookies/sessions in iFrames is something I've worked with before. You could probably use a different subdomain, which would be easiest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you fully control the webstack wouldn't it be easier to add a preview parameter that treats the user as unauthenticated?

For instance:

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com?preview=1" width="640" height="480" />
```

Followed by bypassing your authorization checks if the preview flag exists.

Comment: I think that sounds like a good idea, and you can easily adapt this same method to optionally serve the mobile version like the question mentions.

Comment: In all honesty, we already do have a "Preview" mode in our auth'ed mode that uses a URL param, but it shows a 40px bar across the top that says "This is a preview of your website" and it has a button to go back to Edit mode. We didn't want to show this top-bar in the preview iFrames; we wanted exactly what the end-users see. That being said, it sounds like controlling cookies isn't possible, so I will have to add some kind of way to access preview mode without the top bar. Thanks!