# Can an iframe be created without cookie data?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Using JavaScript, is it possible to inject an iframe and have the iframe hold no cookie/session data? Effectively an 'incognito' iframe?

The reason for this is a Chrome extension I was thinking about, where I'd like to display a preview of pre-auth pages of other websites, and so to ensure they're not redirected the iframe would ideally non use existing cookie data.

I know this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641843/use-an-iframe-without-session-or-cookie-data-incognito), but I don't have full control of the pages I'm previewing in the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use any HTTP-only cookies, you could save a copy of all cookies in `localStorage`, remove all cookies, load the iframe, and restore the cookies from `localStorage`.

Pseudo-code:

```
localStorage.setItem("cookies", document.cookie);
removeAllCookies();
openIframe();
document.cookie = localStorage.cookies;
localStorage.removeItem("cookies");
```

Another way is to create a proxy on your server, which wouldn't use cookies. For example request to `http://example.com/proxy?url=/preview` would make a request to `http://example.com/preview` without cookies.